# Biztalk Mapper XSLT Compile Error

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-mapper

I'm mapping relationship data based on a type Mother/Father etc.  when extracting the data from a table looping functoid and checking for a type of Father, Mother etc. I am getting the following error:

> XSL transform error:. XSLT compile error at (1220,45). See InnerException for details. 'userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:) , "FATHER")' is an invalid XPath expression. 'userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:) , "FATHER")' has an invalid qualified name.

### Source extract example

```
<relationships>
   <RelationshipType>Father</RelationshipType>
   <Details>
      <Title>MR</Title>
      <Fullname>Surname, forename</Fullname>
      <etc...>
   </Details>
</relationships>
```

It's appears that the compiler is missing the $var:XXX value, it is unclear on how this is missing presently as this is system generated.  Any ideas on how to track this back to the map?

Comment: It isn't complaining about your XML input document. It's complaining about the XSLT stylesheet being generated by the mapper. Apparently whatever XSLT processor you're using hasn't been told how to use the `userCSharp:LogicalEQ()` extension function.  You need to look at how the XSLT is actually being generated and executed.

Comment: Thank you @keshlam I've been using the logicalEQ() functoid in different sections of the map with no issue so would this point at not the extension function but something else?

Comment: "$var:".. shouldn't it be "$var"?

Comment: Thanks @LingamurthyCS I've taken another look at the generated XLS and noticed that the variables it is complaining about is missing the variable node number that it is trying to compare the string "Farther" with.  As this is all system generated I'll go back and check the table looping functoid and see if this is causing the issue.

Comment: Just to update, issue is now resolved .. Issued seemed to be linked with a tabel looping functoid.  Links were removed and re added which resolved the issue.

Comment: I've ended up removing the links from the looping table and re-applying the links out to the link extractors and then tested the map output which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, issue is now resolved.

Visual Studio issue seemed to be linked with a tabel looping functoid, needed to remove the functoid and links before re-adding to resolve the issue.